# Расчет площади в зависимости от вводимого количества, без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая конструкция в которую можно ввести количество товара:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ minimum }}" data-minimum="{{ minimum }}" id="input-quantity" class="qty-switch__input form-control" />
                                    <div>
```

и конструкция с постоянной величиной
`<div class="product-data__item square"><div class="product-data__item-div"><span class="product-data__item-span">{{ text_square }}:</span></div> {{ square }}</div>`

Соответственно  в третей конструкции должна выводится площадь (сумма)
`<div class="square"> тут сумма</div>`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.qty-switch__input')
const elem = document.querySelector('.elem')
const abcde = document.querySelector('.abcde')

input.addEventListener('input',e => {
    abcde.innerHTML = `${+e.target.value + +elem.innerHTML}`
})
```

```css
.abcde{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
        <input class="qty-switch__input" type="text"/>
        <div class="elem">5</div>
        <div class="abcde"></div>
    </div>
```

а вот как рассчитать площадь википедия в помощь

Comment: Спасибо, у меня оказывается переменная из value в этой конструкции

Comment: @Mr.Acula не за что рад помочь

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, у меня оказывается переменная из value bp из этой конструкции

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ minimum }}" data-minimum="{{ minimum }}" id="input-quantity" class="qty-switch__input form-control" />
                                <div>
```

передается сразу в скрипт, заметил так как в при просмотре кода в браузере value="{{ minimum }}" не меняется хотя цифры вводятся.